# Foreach loop depending on files in directory

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

Is there a way to create a foreach loop, that will run for however many instances of a filename with a sequential number exists in a directory?

For example I have one directory with images. The images will have filenames such as these:

```
firstname-lastname_before1.jpg
firstname-lastname_after1.jpg
firstname-lastname_before2.jpg
firstname-lastname_after2.jpg
firstname2-lastname2_before1.jpg
firstname2-lastname2_after1.jpg
firstname2-lastname2_before2.jpg
firstname2-lastname2_after2.jpg
```

This essentially shows photos belonging to two people. Each person has four photos, two sets of two photos, a before and after.

I can already handle the individual names when echoing out, but I'm trying to find a way to set a foreach loop that will find all sequential instances of the condition that's currently applied.

i.e. If I'm viewing a page for one person, the foreach loop should run through all files relating to that person.

At the moment I just have one hard-coded instance of the block I want to loop.

```
<div class="photo-set col-md-4">
<figure class="cd-image-container">
<?php $procedure = get_post_custom_values('Procedure'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()."/img/before-after/".preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", strtolower($procedure[0]))."_".preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", strtolower($post->post_title))."_after1.jpg";?>" alt="Original Image">
<span class="cd-image-label" data-type="original">After</span>
<div class="cd-resize-img">
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()."/img/before-after/".preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", strtolower($procedure[0]))."_".preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", strtolower($post->post_title))."_before1.jpg";?>" alt="Modified Image">
<span class="cd-image-label" data-type="modified">Before</span>
</div>
<span class="cd-handle"></span>
</figure>
</div>
```

This is just using before1 and after1, as I wanted to style it up first.

So to summarise, my question is: Can I have a foreach loop that will find all files that match the condition below, that are sequentially named, and sort them into a set of 2 (for before and after)?

UPDATE:

I've tried using the glob function, but I'm really not sure this is what I'm looking. After using this code:

```
$procedures = get_post_custom_values('Procedure');
$procedure = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", strtolower($procedures[0]));
$patientName = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", strtolower($post->post_title));
foreach(glob('img/before-after/*$patientName*/*.jpg') as $filename) {
```

Nothing is being returned on the page. I'm not sure on how the glob expression should be. As it needs to firstly find a directory that matches $patientName, and then inside there are loads of files with different procedures in the title. Like this for an example:

```
tummy-tuck_john-smith_before1.jpg
tummy-tuck_john-smith_after1.jpg
tummy-tuck_john-smith_before2.jpg
tummy-tuck_john-smith_after2.jpg
nose-reshaping_john-smith_before1.jpg
nose-reshaping_john-smith_after1.jpg
```

etc. So how can I code it so that it will pull the correct files (in sets of two, as I have a before and after for each), for the patient name, and the procedure?

UPDATE:

This code also returns nothing, and I don't know why? The $files array is returning as 0.

```
$procedures = get_post_custom_values('Procedure');
$procedure = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", strtolower($procedures[0]));
$patientName = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", strtolower($post->post_title));
$directory = get_template_directory_uri()."/img/before-after/".$patientName."/";
$files = glob($directory.'*', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $filename) {
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you heard of [glob](http://php.net/glob)

Comment: I don't see how glob is going to do what I'm looking for, surely I'd need something a bit larger, or more functional? Would you be able to help with a possible scenario using my condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [glob()](http://php.net/glob) function. You can pass first param as pattern and loop through the results of the function.

Example

```
 foreach(glob('[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z_0-9]+.jpg') as $filename)
 {
    echo $filename;
 }
```

You can also use `\w` but it depends on your conditions.

Comment: I'm not totally convinced this is the right function for what I need. I think I'm going to be needing two loops here, possibly one inside another. As each instance of the first loop will need to then loop how ever many images are sequential that relate to the first loop. Can you explain the pattern you've used above?

Comment: This pattern fits the files you put in your post. [a-zA-Z-0-9] at least one character which is letter,digit or - then '-' then the same at previous and then it should end it .jpg

Comment: Can I replace the a-z with variables?

Comment: Sorry but I'm really not understanding this. This pattern is just going to return every file that's in there surely?

Comment: if u want every file u could go with `glob(*.*);`  you can replace anything with variables if you don't want range you can write for example

`glob("image-*.*jpg);` it will fit all images started by "image-" ending with extenstion .jpg

Comment: I certainly dont want to pull every file. The only files I want to pull will be the persons name, which can be set to variables, but I'm just asking if I can insert variables into the pattern. something like `glob(".$customer.")` but where $customer can be anywhere in the filename. Is that possible?

Comment: Okay, just so I've got it right.. if my filenames are firstname-surname_somethingelse_before1.jpg and firstname-surname_somethingelse_after1.jpg, just having $customer will return both of these?

Comment: I have updated my question, the glob doesn't seem to return anything. Even with the long example you provided.